# show scrollbar on scroll otherwise hide it keeping its z-index above all

Tags: jquery, css

**Description**

I want to hide the scroll bar if the user is not scrolling on the page. As soon as he starts to scroll on the page the scrollbar should become visible.

this code lets me do any thing when the scroll begins

```
$("#element").on("scroll",function(){});
```

lets me add a class to the div where

```
-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 0px !important;
}
```

this css really hides the bar away.

**The Problem**

When the user scrolls, the bar gets displayed but it takes a little space in the dive being scrolled in, which disturbs the placing of the other divs as well.

**What I want**

what I want is to show the scrollbar on scroll but somehow change its z-index so that when it gets displayed it doesn't occupy the space in the div ....

**What Have I done up till now**

I have styled the scrollbar
worked on its show/hide toggle when user scrolls all that is left is the problem I have discussed above ... Is any one familiar with that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome you say...  :)

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xizige/1/edit)**

The **only** way I find really easy to do it is to use a predefined space where the scrollbars will appear. Now, without messing with paddings, positions, wrappers, etc etc  the simplest solution is:

**make the scrollbars *transparent***!

So by default add a class that "transparents" your scrollbar elements:

```
<div id="element" class="hideScroll"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hideScroll::-webkit-scrollbar{
  background:transparent;
}
.hideScroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: transparent;
}
```

**On scroll remove that class** (to apply default styles)!

```
var scrollTimeout;
$(".hideScroll").on("scroll",function(){
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
  var $that = $(this);

  $that.removeClass('hideScroll');
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
     $that.addClass('hideScroll');
  },220);
});
```

and re-add it after a desired timeout.

Comment: " use a predefined space where the scrollbars will appear" This is the line I was looking for ... thanks man you are awsome :)